How to change color from DropdownMenu.ItemTitle from zeego
I am trying to use the dropdown from the Zeego library for React Native (version "zeego": "^2.0.4").
However, for some reason that I haven't been able to figure out yet, the dropdown appears with a black background and black text as well.
I have already made several attempts to change it, but I can't get it to work. My last attempt, as you can see in the code, was to try to override the components following the instructions from the website, but unfortunately, it didn't work.
I am attaching how it looks on my phone.
Thank you in advance for your help
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { Colors } from '@/constants/Colors';
import * as DropdownMenu from 'zeego/dropdown-menu';
import * as Clipboard from 'expo-clipboard';
import { toast } from 'sonner-native';
import { styled } from 'dripsy'
import { ComponentProps } from 'react';

type MoreButtonProps = {
  pageName: string;
};

const DripsyTitle = styled(DropdownMenu.ItemTitle)({
  fontSize: '100',
  lineHeight: '1',
  fontFamily: 'root',
  zIndex: 1,
  color: 'white',
})

const DropdownMenuItemTitleTest = DropdownMenu.create(
  (props: ComponentProps<typeof DropdownMenu.ItemTitle>) => {
    const color = 'red';
    return <DripsyTitle {...props} sx={{ color }} />
  },
  'ItemTitle'
)

const DripsyItem = styled(DropdownMenu.Item)({
  height: 40,
  color: 'red',
})
 
const DropdownMenuItem = DropdownMenu.create(DripsyItem, 'Item')

const MoreButton = ({ pageName }: MoreButtonProps) => {

  const copyToClipboard = async () => {
    const path = `todolist://(authenticated)/(tabs)/${pageName.toLowerCase()}`;
    await Clipboard.setStringAsync(path);
    toast.success(`Page Link copied to your clipboard`);
  };

  return (
    <DropdownMenu.Root>
      <DropdownMenu.Trigger>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} activeOpacity={0.6}>
          <Ionicons name="ellipsis-horizontal-outline" size={30} color={Colors.primary} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </DropdownMenu.Trigger>

      <DropdownMenu.Content
              loop
              side="bottom"
              align="center"
              alignOffset={0}
              avoidCollisions
              collisionPadding={10}
              sideOffset={5}>
        <DropdownMenu.Item
          key="link"
          textValue={`Copy Link to ${pageName}`}
          onSelect={copyToClipboard}>
          <DropdownMenu.ItemTitle>Copy</DropdownMenu.ItemTitle>
          <DropdownMenu.ItemIcon
            ios={{
              name: 'link',
              pointSize: 24,
            }}
            androidIconName="ic_menu_add"></DropdownMenu.ItemIcon>
        </DropdownMenu.Item>

        <DropdownMenu.Group>
          <DropdownMenuItem key="select">
            <DropdownMenuItemTitleTest>Select Tasks</DropdownMenuItemTitleTest>
            <DropdownMenu.ItemIcon
              ios={{
                name: 'square.stack',
                pointSize: 24,
              }}
              androidIconName="sym_action_email"></DropdownMenu.ItemIcon>
          </DropdownMenuItem>
        </DropdownMenu.Group>
      </DropdownMenu.Content>
    </DropdownMenu.Root>
  );
};

export default MoreButton;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    padding: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
});

